Why does Powershell Where-Object not find an exe that is on the path? While where.exe succeeds
In PowerShell, where.exe finds the thing I'm looking for. Where-Object does not. Why?
PS C:\Users\dpchi> where wget.exe
PS C:\Users\dpchi> where.exe wget.exe
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\wget.exe
PS C:\Users\dpchi> where.exe where.exe
C:\Windows\System32\where.exe
PS C:\Users\dpchi> where-object where.exe
PS C:\Users\dpchi> (get-host).version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
7      4      6      -1


where-object (or where or ?) filters objects FROM A COLLECTION SUPPLIED TO IT by a pipeline or argument -- it doesn't go searching for files anywhere, much less on PATH, like where.exe (and which or command -v on (most) Unix)

The PS equivalent for where.exe would be Get-Command.

where-object is not in any way equivalent to where.exe
where.exe:
WHERE [/R dir] [/Q] [/F] [/T] pattern...

Description:
    Displays the location of files that match the search pattern.
    By default, the search is done along the current directory and
    in the paths specified by the PATH environment variable.

Where-Object
SYNOPSIS
    Selects objects from a collection based on their property values.

If you first filled a collection with all files in the current directory and $env:path, and then ran where-object against that, you would have something like where.exe
